Python Tkinter image labels displaying background colour instead of the images
I'm a rookie programmer looking to develop a sort of "surface generator" for funzies. I have a problem though, when generating all of the tiles present in the script, instead of it using the 19x19 tiles I saved as pngs, it merely displays background colour, in this case being transparent.
And I have no idea why. Would any kind soul look at my code and tell me why is this happening?
The function causing this issue is the importtiles function.
# IMPORTS
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import random

#DIVIDE GREENHOUSE POWER BY 60 TO OBTAIN DESIRED TEMPERATURE !!

#DEFINE
def importtiles():
    count = 0
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    f0 = 'andesite.png'
    f1 = 'sand.png'
    for i in range(1, 1008):
        np = open('PlanetSurface.txt', 'r')
        #print(i)
        material = np.readline(i)
        length = len(material)
        if length > 1:
            material = material[:-1]
        print(material)
        if material == '1':
            f = 'andesite.png'
        elif material == '0':
            f = 'sand.png'
        else:
            input('Error')
            #Intentionally crashes the script
            gorbashovodarasboda = 888 + 'webiwabo'
        if count == 42:
            c2 = c2 + 19
            c1 = 0
            count = 0
        print(i)
        tile = PhotoImage(file=f)
        exec('t'+str(i)+'= tk.Label(g,image=tile,bg="pink")')
        exec('t'+str(i)+'.place(x=c1, y=c2)')
        print(c1)
        c1 = c1 + 19
        count = count + 1
def newplanet(name):
    np = open('Planet.txt', 'w')
    np.write(name + '\nTemperature\n2000\nEquator no greenhouse aiming temperature\n(-7)\nCarbon Dioxide\n450000\nWater Vapor\n50000\nOxygen\n0\nGreenhouse Power\n5371\nCalculated Base Temperature With Greenhouse\n91')
def surfacegen():
    np = open('PlanetSurface.txt', 'w')
    ti = random.randint(0,1)
    np.write(str(ti)+'\n')
    np = open('PlanetSurface.txt', 'a')
    for i in range(0,1007):
        toss = random.randint(0,3)
        if toss == 3:
            ti = random.randint(0, 1)
        np.write(str(ti)+'\n')
tilecount = 0
choice = input('Do you wish to create a new planet or to load an existing one? \n'+'Answer with 1 or 2. ')

#BEGIN

if choice == '1':
    name = input("Type in the name of your planet ")
    newplanet(name)
    surfacegen()
    g = tk.Tk()
    g.geometry('800x600')
    g.resizable(0, 0)
    g.configure(background='black')
    g.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", 'pink')
    importtiles()
    g.update()
    input('end')
else:
    #ELIF to be added
    print('doo doo')


I attempted to generate 1000 tiles spread across several rows. The script generated this fine however it generated it with background colours instead of the tile pngs I assigned. I expected tiles with respectively grey and yellow pngs, but got all transparent tiles.

U have typo error on line 36  with single quote.  Should be  exec('t'+str(i)+= tk.Label(g,image=tile,bg="pink"))

toyota, it does not solve the issue and the code seems to have the exact same effect when changing that line

All your image names are defined inside function importtiles() and are called 'tile' and that's where they stay! Try storing your images in a list, perhaps called 'tiles' and then use global tiles to access them outside the function.
